# How many ways are there to choose 5 ice cream cones if there are 10 flavors?

Tags: combinatorics

I had this on a test and I gave answer as: (10 C 5) but it was incorrect. Why?
Isn't this just a typical combination problem where you select 5 objects of 10 objects!

**Correct answer:**
$_{(10+5−1)}C_{ 5} = 2002$

Comment: We are allowed to choose $3$ pistachio and $2$ banana.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The combination $_{10}C_5$ shows how many ways we can choose $5$ of the $10$ flavors.

But instead, we can have five ice cream cones with each the same flavor or any number of cones with the same flavor. Assuming the ice cream cones are not distinct (it doesn't matter whether cone $1$ gets vanilla or cone $3$ gets vanilla), the problem is equivalent to finding the number of integer solutions to

> $$x_1+x_2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x_{10}=5$$

where each $x_i\geq 0$ is the number of cones dedicated to flavor $i$.

Since

> $$(x_1+1)+(x_2+1)+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(x_{10}+1)=5+10$$

We can let $x_i+1=y_i$ and we have

$$y_1+y_2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+y_{10}=15$$

where each $y_i\geq1$.

The number of positive solutions is the number of ways we can draw $10-1=9$ lines, from $14$ possible locations, to divide the $15$ elements into $10$ groups, all of which are nonempty and hence $\geq 1$

For example,

$$\star|\star\star|\star|\star\star\star|\star\star\star|\star|\star|\star|\star|\star$$

The number of ways to do this is $\binom{14}{9}$.

The number of of nonnegative solutions is thus 
$$\binom{10+5-1}{9}=\binom{14}{9}=\binom{14}{5}$$

Comment: Personally, I learned the solution for each $x_i\geq 0$ before I learned the solution for each $y_i\geq 1$.  As an aside, the technique employed and proof of result is what is colloquially referred to as [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: I provided a picture-like explanation. How strange! I learned the number of positive solutions first to justify the number of non-negative solutions.

Comment: I think I can picture the way it was explained to you, that you could pick positions *between* the stars to denote how to separate them, each bar must go into a different position.  The combinatorial explanation I received was that the number of stars left of the leftmost corresponds to the number selected for the first category, number between first and second bar correspond to the number selected for the second category, etc... Your example above to me would have looked like $|\star||\star\star|\star\star|||||$ corresponding to $(0,1,0,2,2,0,0,\dots)$

Comment: ...where we don't care if bars are adjacent.  We have $14$ available positions, five of which will be occupied by stars, the remaining by bars.  Arriving at the same $\binom{14}{5}$.  It is entertaining to realize that people are taught different ways, and think in different ways, yet arrive at the same conclusion.  There is more than one correct way of thinking.

Comment: I would describe $\binom{10}{5}$ as the number of ways we can choose five of the ten available flavors.  As you recognized, fewer than five of the flavors can be selected.

Comment: I also think of the number of positive solutions of the equation as primary, and the number of non-negative solutions as derived from that.

Answer (score 5):

Alice: "I'll have a vanilla cone, please."

Bob: "Drat, I wanted vanilla. I guess I'll have to choose something else, maybe chocolate."

...