# In how many ways can b blue balls and r red balls be distributed in n distinct boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can b blue balls and r red balls be distributed in n distinct boxes?

Comment: Since the boxes are distinct (*the question would be very different if they were indistinguishable*) answer the two sub-questions: How many ways can $b$ blue balls be distributed in $n$ distinct boxes?  How many ways can $r$ red balls be distributed in $n$ distinct boxes?  Find the answer to your original question by using the answers to these two smaller questions and applying multiplication principle.

Comment: How many ways can b blue balls be distributed in nn distinct boxes?

Comment: The answer to that smaller question can be found [in an earlier question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837356/counting-non-negative-integral-solutions/1837370#1837370).